# Show that the induced homomorphism $f_\ast : H_0(X) \to H_0(X)$ equals the identity.

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

> Let $X$ be a path-connected space, and let $f: X \to X$ be a continuous map. Show that the induced homomorphism $f_\ast : H_0(X) \to H_0(X)$ equals the identity.

We are to show that $f_\ast - \text{id}_\ast = 0$. Now if $z + \text{Im}(\partial_1) \in H_0(X)$, then $$\begin{align*}(f_\ast-\text{id}_\ast)(z+\text{Im}(\partial_1)) &= f_\ast(z+\text{Im}(\partial_1)) - \text{id}_\ast(z+\text{Im}(\partial_1)) \\ &= f_\# (z) + \text{Im}(\partial_1) - (z + \text{Im}(\partial_1)) .\end{align*}$$

So if I only could show that $f_\# : C_n(X) \to C_n(X)$ which is defined by $$f_\#(\sigma)=f \circ \sigma : \Delta^n \to X$$ is the identity I think I would be done here? Is there some trick to prove this?

Comment: Did you perhaps mean $f: X \rightarrow X$?

Comment: Yes! Sorry. @Aphelli

Comment: Hint: $C_0(X)$ is the free abelian group generated by $X$. Show that the image of $\delta_1$ is the subgroup generated by the $[y]-[x]$, where $x,y \in X$ are in the same path-connected component – so $[x] \longmapsto 1$ is an isomorphism $H_0(X) \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$. Then look what $f$ looks like through this isomorphism.

Answer (score 2):

You should first translate that statement from the language of homology to the language of cycles and boundaries:

- $f_* : H_0(X) \to H_0(X)$ is the identity $\iff$ for each $0$-cycle $c \in Z_0(X)$, $f_\#(c) - c \in \text{Im}(\partial_1)$.

Next, since $Z_0(X)=C_0(X)$, and since $C_0(X)$ is the free abelian group generated by individual points $x \in X$, this is equivalent to

- for each $x \in X$, $f_\#(x)-x \in \text{Im}(\partial_1)$.

And since $f_\#(x)=f(x)$, this is equivalent to

- for each $x \in X$ there exists $c \in C_1(X)$ such that $\partial_1 c = f(x) - x$.

So, given $x$, can you find $c$? (Hint: $X$ is path connected).